# Wet venting shower

Tags: plumbing, drain-waste-vent

I know this comes up fairly often, but I wanted to check nonetheless.

I am roughing in a new shower and lav setup. The lav and shower both feed into a 2" sani tee. The lav has a 1-1/2" vent to the roof.

**I am asking if I need to run a separate dry vent for the shower drain.** I'd like to avoid this but I want to make sure there aren't issues with the proposed wet vent.

The diagram below shows the scheme. The line-drawn part is the dry vent for the shower that I *dont* want to run if possible. I can't take the shower vent straight up as there's a lot of water plumbing (shower valve, etc.) between those studs.

Details:

- 2x8 framing with header joists all around.
- lav and shower are 2" lines under the floor joists. Lav riser and vent is 1-1/2"
- WC last connected downstream with its own vent

Look ok?[image]

Comment: Vent is a vent, as log it has adequate pipe size it will work providing air to the drain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The limiting factor is, then, the "lav riser" at 1.5" and the wet venting capacity of 1.5" pipe under **your** apllicable code (they don't all agree, though they are usually similar.)

Using a 2" "riser" and a 1.5" dry vent above that would be less limiting. *i.e.* don't reduce the lav pipe until you are at the dry vent point above where the trap arm enters it.

Under IPC, 1-1/2" as a wet vent only supports 1 DFU, while 2" as a wet vent supports 4 DFU. A DFU is a "drainage fixture unit" used for sizing drains and vents under code.

A 1-1/2" **dry** vent will vent up to 10 DFUs, for comparison, if it's less than 100 feet in developed length.

A lavatory is one DFU. A shower is at least 2 DFU, (could be more, up to 6 depending on flow rate, but likely not)

1 + 2 = 3 and 1 < 3 < 4 so as I read it, you **need** to make the lavatory riser 2"

*I'm also a highly dubious about the application of a **sanitary tee** where you need a **wye**. Sanitary tees are for horizontal pipes entering vertical pipes. Wyes are for joining two horizontal pipes. That joint will probably clog as drawn, since flow is not directed "downstream" as a wye will do.*

Comment: Ok. I've not glued anything yet (and can take the tee back to home depot ;-) Thanks!

Comment: Beware that if you cut PVC or ABS to "fit" without gluing, it ends up too short when glued...

Comment: Yup. I measure to the inside flange, for 2" that adds 3/4" at each end, for 1-1/2 it adds 11/16".